# Google Big Query- Create Table Schema by CommandLine

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to create table schema manually by command line in BigQuery

ref- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas#specify-schema-manual-cli

**My Command**

`bq load --source_format=CSV EncoreMarketingTest.SchemaTest1231 D:/myfile1.csv qtr:STRING,sales:FLOAT,year:STRING`

It is giving below error, but if i pass only single parameter then its working fine:

**Error:**

```
 Upload complete.
Waiting on bqjob_r1d79e443_00000160c5b1e5d3_1 ... (0s) Current status: DONE
BigQuery error in load operation: Error processing job
'encoremarketingtest:bqjob_r1d79e443_00000160c5b1e5d3_1': Error while reading
data, error message: CSV table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1;
errors: 1.
Failure details:
- file-00000000: Error while reading data, error message: CSV table
references column position 1, but line starting at position:0
contains only 1 columns.
```

Could you please let me know the issue in command ?

Comment: can you share the first 2 lines of your file?

Comment: Are you pointing myfile1.csv ? That file is empty

Comment: Yes. Why is it empty? You're trying to load a file with some data, right? Or, are you just trying to create an empty table? _"It is giving below error, but if i pass only single parameter then its working fine:"_ - what do you mean? `bq load` is for loading a file/data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You question has me a little confused, but I'm going to assume you are trying to create an empty table instead of trying to load a file/data.

You're using `bq load`. You should be using `bq mk`, for example:

```
bq mk --schema name:string,value:integer -t mydataset.newtable
```

See more info [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/bq-command-line-tool#create-empty-table).